# How to use ANOVA1Way

Tags: python, anova

This is my Pandas dataframe:

```
 db.head()
 db.to_csv('ANOVA_TEST.csv')

    grade   class   numgrade  numyear
0   A      Senior        12         4
1   A      Junior        12         3
2   A      Junior        12         3
3   A      Senior        12         4
4   A      Junior        12         3
```

I create two new dataframes, that look like this:

```
num_columns = ['numgrade', 'numyear']
dnum = db [num_columns].copy()
str_columns = ['numgrade', 'class']
dstr = db [str_columns].copy()

dnum.to_csv('ANOVA_TEST_num.csv')
dstr.to_csv('ANOVA_TEST_str.csv')

dnum.head(2)
dstr.head(2)

    numgrade    numyear
0      12         4
1      12         3

    numgrade    class
0      12       Senior
1      12       Junior
```

Just to make sure that everything is in order, here are the value types for each column:

```
print 'dnum["numgrade"]',type(dnum["numgrade"][1])
print 'dnum["numyear"]',type(dnum["numyear"][1])
print 'dstr["numgrade"]', type(dstr["numgrade"][1])
print 'dstr["class"]',type(dstr["class"][1])

>> dnum["numgrade"] <type 'numpy.int64'>
>> dnum["numyear"] <type 'numpy.int64'>
>> dstr["numgrade"] <type 'numpy.int64'>
>> dstr["class"] <type 'str'>
```

Now, I try to use **ANOVA1Way** as described [here](http://pydoc.net/Python/pyvttbl/0.5.2.2/) and [here](http://www.marsja.se/four-ways-to-conduct-one-way-anovas-using-python/), and check the types again after creating the **pyvttbl** dataframe.

```
from pyvttbl import DataFrame
df = DataFrame()
df.read_tbl('ANOVA_TEST_num.csv')
print type(df)
print type (df['numgrade'][1])
print type (df['numyear'][1])

>> <class 'pyvttbl.base.DataFrame'>
>> <type 'numpy.int64'>
>> <type 'numpy.int64'>

aov_pyvttbl = df.anova1way('numgrade', 'numyear')
print aov_pyvttbl

#Lengthy error message ending with:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'NoneType'
```

The same error message is generated also when I try using the "string" version of the independent variable in **'ANOVA_TEST_str.csv'**

Next, thinking that the issue might have to do with conversion and reading back from *csv* files, I try to do it from scratch using the original dataframe, as described [here](http://pydoc.net/Python/pyvttbl/0.5.2.2/pyvttbl.examples.betweenAVOVA_omega-squared/):

```
numdep = db['numgrade'].tolist()
numindep = db['numyear'].tolist()
print len(numdep), type(numdep), type(numdep[0])
print len(numindep), type(numindep), type(numindep[0])

>> 890 <type 'list'> <type 'int'>
>> 890 <type 'list'> <type 'int'>

df3 = DataFrame()
df3['data'] = numdep
df3['conditions'] = numindep
aov = df3.anova1way('data', 'conditions')
```

I get exactly the same error message.  I have also tried converting **numdep** to float, and **numindep** to str and numpy.str, but still getting the same error.
Can anyone figure out what is happenning here?  Appreciate your help.

Using Canopy 1.7.4.3348, jupyter 1.0.0-20, pandas 0.19.0-2 and pyvttbl 0.5.2.2

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a pretty old question but here it goes.

The problem is that pyvttbl relies on old numpy version (<=1.1.x). More details at [1].

**Links**
[1] [https://www.marsja.se/four-ways-to-conduct-one-way-anovas-using-python/]